# Local notification in iOS not working

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I am new to iOS programming,i am trying simple local notification,when user press button i am setting date and time to notification,notification is not triggering.please reply

```
code:

    - (IBAction)sendNotification:(id)sender
    {


        int hour=4;
        int minute=8;
        int month=5;
        int year=2016;
        int day=31;


        NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
        NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
        [components setYear:year];
        [components setMonth:month];
        [components setDay:day];
        [components setHour: hour];
        [components setMinute: minute];
        [components setSecond: 00];
         [components setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
        NSDate * date=[calendar dateFromComponents:components];
        [self scheduleNotificationForData:date];
    }



    -(void)scheduleNotificationForData:(NSDate *)date
    {

        UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

        localNotification.fireDate = date;
        NSLog(@"Notification will be shown on: %@",localNotification.fireDate);

        localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
        localNotification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your notification message"];
        localNotification.alertAction = NSLocalizedString(@"View details", nil);

        /* Here we set notification sound and badge on the app's icon "-1"
         means that number indicator on the badge will be decreased by one
         - so there will be no badge on the icon */
        localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
        localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = -1;

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];


    }

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.

    UILocalNotification * localNotification=[[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
    [localNotification setAlertBody:@"this is notification"];
    [localNotification setFireDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:5]];
    [localNotification setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
    [application setScheduledLocalNotifications:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:localNotification, nil]];


}
```

Comment: what do you get if you log the calculated date and the current date?

Comment: LocalNotification[4304:177672] Notification will be shown on: 2016-05-31 04:52:00 +0000

Comment: i tried simple in did background it is also not working

Comment: Did you register the notification in appdelegate?

Comment: How are testing if the notification is firing or not? Are you manually changing the time on your device?